# what is the path when we use openstack keypair command to vm

Tags: linux, cloud, openstack

when we use `openstack keypair create xxx` commamd and boot a vm with the keypair ,where dose the keypair exist in the vm? I wonder to know

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about a Linux instance that uses cloud-init to configure the VM after booting ...

The public key will be appended to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the admin account.  The private key is not uploaded to the instance.

Comment: thank you for answering the question,i use command "openstack keypair create abc > key.pem",and i found it is a private key file.It will auto create a public key at the same time to upload to the vm?

Comment: Yes.  Sort of.  The public key is generated and stored by the Nova service.  When the instance starts, cloud-init on the instance obtains the public key by querying the metadata service accessed via `http://169.254.169.25` (that is a link-local IP address).